# Can the following lines of code be optimized away?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

Can those lines of code be optimized away?

```
int *ptr = (int *)0x1234;
*ptr = 2;
/* no further code in the scope uses ptr */
```

Can I be sure that for any decent compiler and with any level of optimization, this code will be executed?

Testing it with `-S` flag on two different compilers (`gcc` and `gcc-arm-none-eabi`) shows me this code is not optimized away. But I'm looking for a certain assurance or guideline regarding this specific code.

**Solved *(I believe):***  Accepted answer given by Jonathan Mee, from [Wikipedia - Alias analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_analysis)

> ...if it is not known if p and q alias or not, then no optimizations can be performed and the whole of the code must be executed

To my understanding, `p` can be referred in this example to my `ptr` which points to `0x1234`, and `q` can actually be considered to any type of reference to this address on the program.

Comment: You cannot be sure any compiler will optimize it away, but you can check by reading the assembly listing. Try [`gcc -S`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc "man gcc").

Comment: using `gcc -S` on two different compilers (`gcc` and `gcc-arm`) shows me this code is not optimized away. But I'm looking for a certain assurance

Comment: A useful tool for looking at compiler optimizations is Matt Godbolt's [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/BWDKuQ)

Comment: @user2079303 Well-formed C or ill-formed C++, I think (before the cast was edited in). And for some reason the question has both tags.

Comment: @aschepler oh, I didn't check if other languages were tagged. Well, now the code is well formed in both languages, and C++ is isn't even tagged anymore so my comment serves no purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those cannot be optimized away.

`int* ptr = (int*)0x12345` establishes a pointer to the byte addressed by `0x12345` which you are presumably allocating elsewhere? However such an address, being odd, is not byte aligned which is at best unoptimized.

`*ptr = 2` assigns `2` to that address. Clearly optimizing these lines away would result in a different memory state. Thus they cannot be optimized away.

---

The optimization away of references is allowed by [alias analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_analysis) by which it can be determined whether, "a storage location may be accessed in more than one way"

[c](/questions/tagged/c) participates in [type-based alias analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_analysis#Type-based_alias_analysis):

> 1. Two variables of different types cannot be in the same alias class since it is a property of strongly typed, memory reference-free (i.e., references to memory locations cannot be changed directly) languages that two variables of different types cannot share the same memory location simultaneously.
> 2. Allocations local to the current stack frame cannot be in the same alias class as any previous allocation from another stack frame. This is the case because new memory allocations must be disjoint from all other memory allocations.
> 3. Each record field of each record type has its own alias class, in general, because the typing discipline usually only allows for records of the same type to alias. Since all records of a type will be stored in an identical format in memory, a field can only alias to itself.
> 4. Similarly, each array of a given type has its own alias class.

**2** is the real kicker here, because this isn't allocated locally to the current stack frame, `ptr` could be aliased to any other `int` in the program, thus the compiler cannot optimize it away.

Comment: Can you provide a document reference for that?

Comment: @user2162550 Documentation for what? That changes to memory state cannot be optimized away? It should be noted that this isn't a garbage collected language, any other pointer may be altered to point to and read from this address over the course of the program.

Comment: That needs to be a reinterpret_cast

Comment: It can be optimized away if the compiler do not see any use of this variable. It does not matter if the address is given by the integer number or the &. `volatile` is the must

Comment: And the question is about C not C++

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Yeah... it wasn't originally :(

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks... but it looks like the goal posts moved to C anyway :/

Comment: @PeterJ_01 `It can be optimized away if the compiler do not see any use of this variable.` do you mean another use of `ptr` beside `*ptr = 2` ? I'm trying to understand the case in which you say this code can be optimized away.

Comment: @JonathanMee Please note the conditions for your 4 points - `If the language being compiled is type safe, the compiler's type checker is correct, and the language lacks the ability to create pointers referencing local variables` please note that `C` not matching the last requirement `the language lacks the ability to create pointers referencing local variables`

Comment: @JonathanMee also, regarding your explanation `Clearly optimizing these lines away would result in a different memory state`, you can also say it on assignment on local variable on stack, lets say `func() { int x; x = 3; return 0; }` in this case the compiler can optimize `x` away, but this will result in different memory state up until the point where the address of `x` on stack (aka memory) gets override by another function's stack

Comment: @user2162550 Optimizing `x` out of `func() { int x; x = 3; return 0; }` will not result in a different memory state after `func` returns. `ptr` hopefully points to something allocated on the heap, but it could point to another variable, it could even be the address of `func`'s `x` variable. Thus, optimizing this variable out would result in a different memory state *even after* `ptr`'s scope had closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure a compiler will write the value `2` to the address `0x12345`, you'll be interested by the `volatile` qualifier.

```
volatile int *ptr = (int*) 0x12345; // hardware special address
*ptr = 2;
```

This means every read or write to `*ptr` is to be considered to have side-effects by the compiler and cannot be optimized<sup>1</sup>.

Note though, crafting such a pointer and writing to it has [implementation-defined behaviour](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5)<sup>2</sup>, and you should refer to your compiler documentation anyway.

---

<sup>1)</sup> From C++ lastest draft (this question was tagged C++ in its first version), `[dcl.type.cv]/6` is given below.
<sup>2)</sup> Credit to user StoryTeller.

---

> #### [`[dcl.type.cv]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#6)
>
> [ Note: volatile is a hint to the implementation to avoid aggressive optimization involving the object because the value of the object might be changed by means undetectable by an implementation. Furthermore, for some implementations, volatile might indicate that special hardware instructions are required to access the object. See [intro.execution] for detailed semantics. In general, the semantics of volatile are intended to be the same in C++ as they are in C. — end note ]

Comment: I know this. But do I really need the `volatile` here? is there a rule matching this code, according to it the compiler will decide to optimize it?

Comment: @user2162550 - The rule is only that a compiler may not optimize given the volatile. No such universally applicable guarantees exist without it.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: Hum. Could have sworn I deleted that comment along with my answer.

Comment: Sadly the goalpost movement from C++ to C has affected this answer as well :(